# CMake/Qt - libcrypto-3-x64.dll was not found

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(BeastBurst VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX C)


set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Network LinguistTools)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Network LinguistTools)


find_package(BZip2 REQUIRED)
find_package(zstd REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)


if(ZLIB_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "ZLIB_LIBRARIES: ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
endif()

include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_subdirectory(Agent)
add_subdirectory(BBPatcher)
add_subdirectory(BBPatchTool)
add_subdirectory(dep/socketio)
add_subdirectory(dep/hdiffpatch/source)
add_subdirectory(dep/hdiffpatch/lzma/C)
add_subdirectory(dep/quazip)
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
set(TS_FILES BeastBurst_en_US.ts)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        beastburst.cpp
        beastburst.h
        beastburst.ui
        components/popupmenu.h
        components/popupmenu.cpp
        ${TS_FILES}
        Model/User.cpp
        Model/User.h
        MainMenuButton.cpp
        MainMenuButton.h
        GameButton.cpp
        GameButton.h
        ZipExtractThread.cpp
        ZipExtractThread.h
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(BeastBurst
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        login.h login.cpp login.ui
        resources.qrc
        starter.h starter.cpp
        game.h game.cpp game.ui
        home.h home.cpp home.ui
        store.h store.cpp store.ui
        games.h games.cpp games.ui

    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET BeastBurst APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation

    qt_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(BeastBurst SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(BeastBurst
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()

    qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
endif()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    target_compile_definitions(BeastBurst PRIVATE DEVELOPMENT_ENV)
else()
    target_compile_definitions(BeastBurst PRIVATE PRODUCTION_ENV)
endif()

target_include_directories(BeastBurst PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BBPatcher/)
target_include_directories(BeastBurst PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Model/)
target_link_libraries(BeastBurst PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} sioclient_tls BBPatcher HDiffPatch QuaZip)
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)  # Linux
    target_link_libraries(BeastBurst PRIVATE crypto ssl)
endif()
# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.BeastBurst)
endif()

add_dependencies(BeastBurst BeastBurst_Agent)

set_target_properties(BeastBurst PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)


include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS BeastBurst
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(BeastBurst)
endif()
```

All packages are found and the app is build successfully. However I can't ship it like that.

When my app is build I can see that it places `zlib1.dll` and `bz.dll` in the build directory next to BeastBurst.exe. However it does to place `libcrypto-3-x64.dll` and `libssl-3-x6.dll` which are part of OpenSSL, and therefore when somebody tries to open it it screams for these missing dlls.

Why is that and how can I make it so that it places these two there as well ?